# org.junit.ComparisonFailure Issue - the values should match but they don't

Tags: java, rest-assured

Trying to validate the 100.0 from JSON response in my test but the output has the brackets in it somehow ;can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[100.0]> but was:<[[100.0]]>
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
```

THE JSON RESPONSE

```
**"currentPlanType": "CAT",
    "accumDetailsMapList": {
        "MOD": [
            {
                "accumPlanTypeId": 0000,
                "deductiblePlanTypeId": 123456,
                "businessTypeCode": "C",
                "planTypeCode": "EAD",
                "limitMetCode": false,
                "individAmt": 100.00,**
```

The Test

```
public void S1StatusCodeValidation() {
   String accumlStatement1 = S1Response.jsonPath().getString("accumDetailsMapList.MOD.individAmt");
   Assert.assertEquals("100.0",accumlStatement1);
```

Comment: You need to add your test code to your question.

Comment: MOD  is an array, not an object.

Comment: not exactly sure how to write it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `accumDetailsMapList.MOD.individAmt` will return a list of `individAmt`, that's why it is `[100.0]`, not `100.0`
- To make it correct, you need add index to take exact `individAmt` you want. In this case, it's `accumDetailsMapList.MOD[0].individAmt`

This code would work:

```
float accumlStatement1 = S1Response.jsonPath().get("accumDetailsMapList.MOD[0].individAmt");
Assert.assertEquals(100.0, accumlStatement1);
```

Comment: This worked but I had to put a slightly different assert code

float accumlStatement1 = S1Response.jsonPath().get("accumDetailsMapList.DED[0].individualLimitAmount");
Assert.assertEquals(100.0 ,accumlStatement1,0.0);

Comment: @KomroniMustafoi It depends on test framework you're working on. I use JUnit5 so it doesn't need `float delta` parameter. Anw, if my answer solves your problem, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
thanks for the help lucas-nguyen-17


float accumlStatement1 = S1Response.jsonPath().get("accumDetailsMapList.DED[0].individualLimitAmount");
    Assert.assertEquals(100.0 ,accumlStatement1,0.0);
```

//float expected, float actual , float delta .

it does not allow only float expected and actual for some reason